# Spring Security suddenly stopped authenticating even tho it was working fine before

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

This is very weird. Authentication was working fine but when I launched the project today, its not working anymore. I have absolutely no idea what is the problem. When I enter CORRECT data (yes, I'm 100% sure it's correct), and I debug it, SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION contains BadCredentialsException. Here's what is returned by my UserDetailsService class:
[image]

So as you can see, it gets the information from database, builds User and returns it but spring security went crazy for some reason.
My security config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.sikor.security" />

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/game/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <form-login password-parameter="password"  username-parameter="username" login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/game/profile" login-processing-url="/processLogin" authentication-failure-url="/login"/>
    <logout logout-url="/game/logout" logout-success-url="/logout" delete-cookies="true" invalidate-session="true"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="bCryptPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

I don't have any filters, springSecurityFilterChain is the only one so I guess theres no point to paste my web.xml Any help would be really appreciated. It's driving me nuts.
By the way, Yesterday, I linked my account table with another one using @OneToOne and lazy fetch type but I don't think it has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found it. The problem was that I had JPA annotations on getters. When I placed them on the fields, it started working again.
I put them on getters yesterday because people said it's convenient when you have to make a custom getter for example. I'd love to hear from someone why in my case it stopped spring security from working properly.